# Logs suddendendly very verbose on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I have a django app deployed on heroku and I am fetching my logs with papertrails.

Since my last push on heroku I have started getting logs from every connection to my app of the form:

```
"Jan 09 01:42:22 my_app_name app/web.1: some_ip - - [09/Jan/2018:03:42:21 -0600]
GET /main_site/static/main_site/images/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200
- "https://my_url" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36"
```

for every `GET` or `POST` request that I get.

As far as I can tell I did not touch anything related to logging so I am wondering whether anything can have changed somewhere and more importantly, how can I filter those out.

My logging configuration is as follow, in particular anything going through django should have a different formatting so this seems to be possibly coming straight from Heroku.

My logging configuration, if useful:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'formatters': {
    'standard': {
        'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(module)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
        'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'standard',
        "stream": sys.stdout
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'propagate': True,
    },
    'my_app': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
```

}

Comment: Have you tried to set the `my_app` logger's level to something higher, like `WARNING`?

Comment: Yes, doesn't help. Note that this logging doesn't seem to go through django's logging as, unlike my other logs, it doesn't mention the log level